# MemoryPack.MemoryPackSerializationException : <class> is not registered in this provider

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

I would like to test [MemoryPack](https://github.com/Cysharp/MemoryPack)  serializer, but obtain following exception on "MemoryPackSerializer.Serialize()" call.

```
Unhandled exception. MemoryPack.MemoryPackSerializationException: console_memorypack1.Person is not registered in this provider.
```

This is a basic .net6 console app :

Person.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MemoryPack;

namespace console_memorypack1
{
    [MemoryPackable]
    public partial class Person
    {
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```
// See https://aka.ms/new-console-template for more information
using console_memorypack1;
using MemoryPack;

Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");

var v = new Person { Age = 40, Name = "John" };

var bin = MemoryPackSerializer.Serialize(v);
var val = MemoryPackSerializer.Deserialize<Person>(bin);
```

Read doc and googled error without success.
I cannot see what is missing.

Many thanks

Comment: Very strange : object can be serialized if partial class is defined  inside main file Program.cs

Comment: Use generic version of `Serialize<Person>(v)`

Comment: Hi, I replaced  `var bin = MemoryPackSerializer.Serialize(v);` with  `var bin = MemoryPackSerializer.Serialize<Person>(v);` but still obtain  "_Application.Person is not registered in this provider._"

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue but in my case I forgot to mark one of the classes as `[MemoryPackable]`.

Answer (score -1):

**Update** : Problem solved by using "MemoryPack" package and not "MemoryPack.Core"

[Solution by package author](https://github.com/Cysharp/MemoryPack/issues/119)

Comment: Can you elaborate? I checked the author solution but in my case the csproj contains "MemoryPack" and it still uses the MemoryPack.Core dll. If you could explain what exactly you did to solve it, it can help others.

Comment: As said by author "neuecc" (see link),   you must check that csproj file references "MemoryPack " (and not "MemoryPack.Core")  :   <PackageReference Include="MemoryPack" Version="1.9.12" />